# In Polymer, is it possible to use an array of parameters to make an iron-ajax call?

Tags: ajax, polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

So what I am picturing is an array of parameters that I have which contain a list of id's, let's call this Array1. These id's are going to be used as parameters for an ajax call to the same url. When it makes the call I want to push some info off of the ajax call to a common array (Array2) and then move on to the next id in Array1. Is this possible to implement with Polymer? And if so where do I begin?

Code:

```
        <iron-ajax id="ajax"
               auto="false"
                url='http://url.com/details?Id='
                handle-as="json"
                on-response="handleResponse"></iron-ajax>



<script>
    var playerData = [];
    Polymer({
        is: 'my-team',
        properties: {
        },
        attached: function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                this.$.ajax.url = 'http://url.com/details?Id=' + currentTeam[i];
                console.log(array[i]);
            }
        },
        handleResponse: function (r) {
            // do something;
            playerData.push(r.detail.response);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Are you going to send an ajax call for each id? I strongly advise you to change your backend so that it can receive an array of id's so they can all be handled using a single call.

Comment: @jdepypere that was the original plan, but I like what you commented below better.

Comment: @jdepypere do you mind looking at the updated code? For some reason it looks like it only grabs the last element in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, I think this will work. It might not be the most efficient way of doing it, but gets the job done.

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{array1}}" as="id">
  <iron-ajax auto
             url='http://website.com/{{id}}'
             handle-as="json"
             on-response="handleResponse">
   </iron-ajax>
</template>
```

Add a function handleReponse

```
 handleResponse: function(r) {
      var response = r.detail.response;
      // do something;
    },
```

**Edit based on jdepypere's suggestion (No Dom-Repeat):**

```
  <iron-ajax id="ajax" url='http://website.com/'
             handle-as="json"
             on-response="handleResponse">
   </iron-ajax>

attached: function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.array1.length; i++) {
       this.$.ajax = 'http://website.com/' + this.array1[i];
    }
},
handleResponse: function(r) {
          var response = r.detail.response;
          // do something;
},
```

## **Edit2 added GenerateRequest method (Now Working)**:

```
  <iron-ajax id="ajax" url='http://website.com/'
                 handle-as="json"
                 on-response="handleResponse">
       </iron-ajax>

 properties: {
          array1: {
            value: ['123', '123555', '235']
          }
        },
        attached: function() {
          console.log('attached');
          for (var i = 0; i < this.array1.length; i++) {
            console.log(i);
            this.$.aj.url = 'http://website.com/' + this.array1[i];
            this.$.aj.generateRequest();
          }
        },
        handleResponse: function(r) {
          var response = r.detail.response;
          console.log('handle');
          // do something;
        },
```

Comment: If this is what he desires, using a single `<iron-ajax>` element would be much cleaner. The `<iron-ajax>` element can send multiple calls while one of the previous has not been fully handled yet, so this would be a much cleaner approach. This would require setting `auto` to false to prevent the built-in debouncer to cancel requests due to rapid changing of url and params.

Comment: @jdepypere I updated the code based on your suggestion. Hope it works

Comment: @ChrisW I like where you are going with this but I have a couple of questions. What exactly are you doing with the params and the "CHANGETHIS" I don't see how they are getting set. Also, what is the purpose of the attached function where you set the end of the url to one of the ID's?

Comment: To my last point, shouldn't changing the parameters take away the need for changing the URL?

Comment: Yes you're correct. I originally I was imagining you using params but that's not necessary. I'll edit it out the params.

Comment: @ChrisW seems like it would work, but after implementing it seems like it only performs the iron-ajax call based on the last element in the array? Weird

Comment: @tehman try now. I force a request by calling generateRequest()

Comment: Awesome! That looks like it worked. You might want to edit your answer to  change it so that iron-ajax auto="false", but other than that the solution does work. Thank you